# How to work with map property in RQL (Oracle's ATG Web Commerce)

Tags: repository, atg

We use Oracle's ATG Web Commerce for our project. And currently we need construct RQL query which obtain products which SKU's tacticalTradeStatuses contains certain status and ordered by status value.

I briefly describe the relationship between entities: Product item descriptor contains list of SKUs. Each SKU contains map tacticalTradeStatuses (key - tactical trade status, value - sequense)

For example, how to obtain all products which SKU's tacticalTradeStatuses property contains key 'BEST_SELLER' and ordered by value associated with key 'BEST_SELLER'.

Key by which we want to select products we want to pass as RQL parameter.

Comment: Do you have any constraints on query like does it have to use Repository API or RQL or SQL (`SqlPassthroughQuery`) would be enough? Also what version of ATG server do you use?

Comment: We use ATG 10.0.3. And our project architect said that we have to avoid SQL.

Comment: I found solution which require divide query on two queries.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT T1.PRODUCT_ID, T4.TACTICAL_TRADING_STATUS_NAME, T4.TACTICAL_TRADING_STATUS_SEQ
   FROM DCS_PRODUCT T1, DCS_PRD_CHLDSKU T2, DCS_SKU T3, KF_SKU_TACTICAL_TRADE_STATUS T4
  WHERE T2.PRODUCT_ID=T1.PRODUCT_ID 
   AND T2.SKU_ID=T3.SKU_ID 
   AND T3.SKU_ID=T4.SKU_ID
   AND T4.TACTICAL_TRADING_STATUS_NAME = 'BEST_SELLER'
  ORDER BY T4.TACTICAL_TRADING_STATUS_SEQ ASC;
  
<query-items item-descriptor="product">
  ID IN { "p320801", "p5925" }
</query-items>

Comment: TACTICAL_TRADING_STATUS_NAME and list of IDs we have to pass as query parameters. But this solution still requires SQL. Also as I know there is restriction of number parameters in IN key word (1024)

Comment: That's why I asked about your constraints first. In the course of last several years I never had to write a RQL query with use of map keys. I also double checked RQL and Repository API, I am not sure if queries with map keys are yet supported by ATG Repository. But if you use `SqlPassthroughQuery` you can have SQL query which returns repository items.

Answer (score 0):

i have two ways to doing that
1) first create a query which fetches all the product based on map key BEST_SELLER
2) Now pass it to foreach droplet and add sort properties. which help to sort the result based on your requirements 
for sorting please refer to below link

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/PageDevGuide/html/s1316foreach01.html
2 way i think is to use query options in RQLStatement.. which work same as sort properties in for each

If you provide some XML Repository structure that will be good..hope it will help you